# Custom gradient with state

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14469.pdf) gradient clipping paper in tensorflow, which entails storing the history of gradient norms.

I assume I need to do this using the `tf.custom_gradient` decorator, but how do I maintain a running list of the gradient norm history? Can I use a closure as in the pytorch version?

For reference, here is the implementation in [pytorch](https://github.com/pseeth/autoclip).

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
from enum import Enum

def _get_grad_norm(model):
    total_norm = 0
    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.grad is not None:
            param_norm = p.grad.data.norm(2)
            total_norm += param_norm.item() ** 2
    total_norm = total_norm ** (1. / 2)
    return total_norm 

# written for pytorch ignite
# fire this on backwards pass
class BackwardsEvents(Enum):
    BACKWARDS_COMPLETED = 'backwards_completed'

def add_autoclip_gradient_handler(engine, model, clip_percentile):
    # Keep track of the history of gradients and select a cutoff
    # to clip values to based on percentile.
    grad_history = []

    @engine.on(BackwardsEvents.BACKWARDS_COMPLETED)
    def autoclip_gradient(engine):
        obs_grad_norm = _get_grad_norm(model)
        grad_history.append(obs_grad_norm)
        clip_value = np.percentile(grad_history, clip_percentile)
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip_value)
```

Comment: I would say it's a lot more "sane" to handle this either inside the optimizer object (which is stateful anyway) or, if you don't want to mess with custom optimizers, inside your "global" code space (assuming you are using custom training loops and have access to gradients via `GradientTape`). Disclaimer: I don't know the paper, so it may well be that a custom gradient is somehow needed for a correct implementation -- but I would avoid it if at all possible.